# CSS: Issue with aligning element to bottom

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm having CSS question on aligning an element vertically.

Please take a look at this URL:
[http://leisureonly.com/gravedigger/grow-up [Possibly NSFW]](http://leisureonly.com/gravedigger/grow-the-fuck-up)

If you look at the sidebar to the right, at the bottom there's a block with an image saying 'Grave Digger'. I want this block to be aligned at the bottom of the sidebar.

I've tried wrapping it in a div and applying vertical-align: bottom to the grave-digger element, but that doesn't offer the desired results. 
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I think the page background just made my eyes explode. I'm not a huge fan of the content either...

Comment: that element does appear at the bottom of the sidebar.. you mean at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Also, your background is tripping me out, yikes.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Luckily Stackoverflow doesn't require you to like the content of a website to answer a question.

Comment: @Andres, I mean totally at the bottom of the sidebar. So that should be to the right of the latest & related posts.

Comment: @JamWaffles: I would imagine that the degree you like the page is increasingly proportional to your age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, beginning with, sidebar_gravedigger is at the bottom of the side_bar, so, the first problem is that the sidebar is that long. If you want that element positioned at the bottom of the container (the parent container of the side_bar), I recommend this:

```
.sidebar_gravedigger {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px; /*container padding*/
}

#sidebar {
    padding-bottom: 500px; /*when the content is short, gravedigger won't be over the bar content.*/
}

.container{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, that totally did it. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this allow for the .sidebar_gravedigger height to change?

Comment: .sidebar_gravedigger will be able to be larger, but as your solution, when the content bar is shorter than the sidebar will happens that the .sidebar_gravedigger will be over the sidebar content. A common solution is to fixing it by adding some padding for spacing the place, another should be to duplicate the .sidebar_gravedigger element and styling with visibility: hidden; and position: static.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.module {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's close, but not quite there. The element now gets aligned to the bottom of the content within the sidebar. So the #sidebar element is not high enough to fill the space of the sidebar, if you get what I'm saying.

Comment: Adding height:100%; to the sidebar should do that.